# Slow upload with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I wrote a program in PyQt4 to upload files using the post request to XFS. Everything is working just fine but speed is extremely low.

With another program I get 70 Mb/s throughput but with something I wrote I just get 8 Mb/s max. What is the reason for the low speed?

I suspect I need to use different connections. I searched and found a reply on Qt from suggest this for QFtp, I don't know if it's working for http or not.

**edit**:add demo for clearing question,It almost cover everything I do for uploading(I didn't test sample code but it should work I guess)

**edit2**:with this code I upload 8 Mb/s,while in the exact situation another program give 70 Mb/s,there is a lot difference in speed

I explained important thing in the code

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
import requests
import time
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, address):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setStretchLastSection(True)
        header.hide()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Add Upload', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleAddUpload)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.netaccess = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self._uploaders = {}

    def handleAddUpload(self):
        #in main program this is a loop actually,to handle batch upload
        #for....
        stream = QtCore.QFile('icon.png')
        if stream.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            self.ts = time.time() #we will use this later
            data = stream
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            button = QtGui.QPushButton('Abort', self.table)
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.handleAbort(row))
            progress = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.table)
            progress.setRange(1, stream.size())
            self.table.setRowCount(row + 1)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 0, button)
            self.table.setCellWidget(row, 1, progress)
            uploader = self._uploaders[row] = Uploader(row, self.netaccess)
            uploader.uploadProgress.connect(self.handleUploadProgress)
            uploader.uploadFinished.connect(self.handleUploadFinished)
            uploader.upload(data, self.address)

    def handleUploadProgress(self, key, sent, total):
        print'upload(%d): %d [%d]' % (key, sent, total)
        #I test it,when I call this three method,upload speed in my local become 3 mb
        #but when I Comment these methods speed is over 70 mb
        #problem is here I guess
        self.humansize(sent, total)
        self.humantransferrate(sent)
        self.timeleft(sent, total)
        #I commented next lines because here we don't have a table but in main
        #program these are not commented and change table cells rapidly

        #self.sentsizelabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(self.humansent))
        #self.totalsizelabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(self.humantotal))
        #self.transferlabel = QtGui.QLabel(str(self.tr))
        #self.timeleftlabel = QtGui.QLabel(str("{0}").format(self.timeLeft))
        #self.table.setCellWidget(key, 1, self.sentsizelabel)
        #self.table.setCellWidget(key, 2, self.totalsizelabel)
        #self.table.setCellWidget(key, 5, self.transferlabel)
        #self.table.setCellWidget(key, 3, self.timeleftlabel)

        progress = self.table.cellWidget(key, 1)
        progress.setValue(sent)

    def handleUploadFinished(self, key):
        print'upload(%d) finished' % key
        button = self.table.cellWidget(key, 0)
        button.setDisabled(True)
        uploader = self._uploaders.pop(key)
        uploader.deleteLater()

    def handleAbort(self, key):
        try:
            self._uploaders[key].abort()
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass

    def humantransferrate(self,sent): #sorry if it's not clean 
        now = time.time() #get time()
        uploadTime = now - self.ts #self.ts is the time() when uploaded started,uploadTime is time between start upload and now
        self.trfirst = (sent/1024)/uploadTime# turning byte to Kb
        if self.trfirst > 1000:#retun better format of transfer rate
            self.trlast = self.trfirst/1024
            self.tr = str('{0:.1f} Mb'.format(self.trlast))
        else:
            self.tr = str('{0:.2f} Kb'.format(self.trfirst))
        return

    def timeleft(self, sent, total):
        leftSize = total-sent
        now = time.time() #right now
        uploadTime = now - self.ts #self.ts is the time() when upload started
        #compute time left
        #here we use Proportion to figure out time left
        param = leftSize * uploadTime
        try:
            timeLen = param/sent
        except: #this is because for very very small files param/sent will return 0
            timeLen = 0.001
        if timeLen > 60:#return best format
            self.timeLeft = '{0:.1f} min'.format(timeLen / 60)
        else:
            self.timeLeft = '{0:.0f} sec'.format(timeLen)


    def humansize(self, sent, total):
        if sent/1000 > 1000: #return right format
            self.humansent = '{0:.1f} Mb'.format(sent/1000000)
        else:
            self.humansent = '{0:.2f} Kb'.format(sent/1000)
        if total/1000 > 1000: #return right format
            self.humantotal = '{0:.1f} Mb'.format(total/1000000)
        else:
            self.humantotal = '{0:.2f} Kb'.format(total/1000)
        return self

class Uploader(QtCore.QObject):
    uploadProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, int, int)
    uploadFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, key, parent):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._key = key
        self._reply = None

    def abort(self):
        if self._reply is not None:
            self._reply.abort()

    def upload(self, data, url):
        if self._reply is None:
            #in here I read from a json file to get cookies,this is fast I guess
            #with open.....
            self._stream = data
            self._multiPart = QtNetwork.QHttpMultiPart(QtNetwork.QHttpMultiPart.FormDataType)
            fileName = QtCore.QFileInfo(self._stream.fileName()).fileName()
            key = 'file'
            imagePart = QtNetwork.QHttpPart()
            imagePart.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentDispositionHeader,
                     "form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"" % (key, fileName))
            imagePart.setBodyDevice(self._stream)
            self._multiPart.append(imagePart)
            #sending login data
            #self._multiPart.append(sessPart)
            #self._multiPart.append(submitPart)
            request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
            request.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader,
  'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % self._multiPart.boundary())
            request.setRawHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0')
            request.setRawHeader('Cookie', 'some cookie from json file')
            self._reply = self.parent().post(request, self._multiPart)
            self._reply.uploadProgress.connect(self.handleUploadProgress)
            self._reply.finished.connect(self.handleFinished)

    def handleUploadProgress(self, sent, total):
        #when I comment this and print transfer rate in here speed is over 70 mb
        self.uploadProgress.emit(self._key, sent, total)


    def handleFinished(self):
        #here I use requests again to get uploaded url from an html page(parsing it) I didn't write it because I it's better to code be shorter
        self._stream.close()
        self._multiPart.deleteLater()
        self._reply.deleteLater()
        self._reply = None
        self.uploadFinished.emit(self._key)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window('http://localhost/upload.php')
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm not sure but I guess if I emit uploadProgress in Uploader.handleUploadProgress() every 5 second problem will solve :-? but don't know how to test it if it work

**edit** : for now problem is solved,I used and try and a if in Window.UploadProgress to make it work,however this is not good way at all,if you guys have any suggestion I'd love to know

Comment: It's really tiresome when you don't bother posting the actual code that you wrote that doesn't work. It's basic etiquette here. -1 In other words: we can't read your mind. Don't expect us to. It's rude.

Comment: To reproduce the problem, please post a *complete*, *self contained* example that does the upload, *and* another one that receives the data, via localhost. That's the minimal testcase that is needed to reproduce the problem. You know Python and PyQt, it shouldn't take more than 10 minutes for you to do so. Anything else is a waste of time for everyone else, since potentially many people may be trying to second guess you, or worse, create test cases that you should have made in the first place.

Comment: Only once you have such a test case you have a somewhat valid assertion that things are bad. For all I know, your 70 Mb/s test was done when the connection was better. You can't know that either. Only a localhost test is valid in this case.

Comment: I will certainly upvote your question once there's a test case that I can copy-paste and run myself and reproduce the slow performance.

Comment: I'll writing a demo right now

Comment: I updated my question and add a sample code which show what I did(you can test it if you remove requests part of code,I guess)

Comment: So did you solve your problem by updating the UI less often? If so, I think this is the right approach - why do you think it is "not a good way"?

Comment: yes,I'm not expert so I thought maybe there is something in pyqt which act better and faster.specialy in this case which upload progress get a lot of resources(i.e 30% CPU for Core2Due)it's important to keep program light,BTW,my program is almost done.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're reading the file using Python's file api, then passing bytes through a `QByteArray`?

Make sure that you're passing an instance of `QFile` as the second argument to the `post` method.

But first of all, post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. It can be just a dozen lines - remember, it's Python, after all. It should roughly look like this:

```py
file = QFile("file.zip")
if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    return
request = QNetworkRequest("http://foo.bar.baz/upload")
reply = networkAccessManager.post(request, file)
```

If you're using a multipart request, it should look roughly like the code below. Thanks to [Andrew Suffield](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2012-June/031609.html) for the `setParent` tip.

```py
filename = "file.zip"
file = QFile(filename)
if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    return
multipart = QHttpMultiPart(QtNetwork.QHttpMultiPart.FormDataType)
filepart = QHttpPart()
filepart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader, 'application/octet-stream')
filepart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest.ContentDispositionHeader, 'form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % ('file', filename))
filepart.setBodyDevice(file)
multipart.append(filepart)
reply = manager.post(request, multipart)
# Hook multipart to the reply so that it sticks around for the lifetime of the request
multipart.setParent(reply)
```

These should perform no worse than equivalent C++ code, so if there is a problem, it's possibly in Qt proper, as long as your other code is sane.

Comment: I pass the file as a QtCore.QFile,then using QhttpMultiPart and QHttpPart I ready it to send over HTTP and I pass QHttpMultiPart as the second parameter to post method(it's like your example just mine have QHttpMultiPart).So now that it's ok.what else it could be ?

Comment: No,I'm using PyQt4,I used pyside tag because almost pyqt and pyside ar the same

Comment: @Mohammadhzp They are most definitely *not* the same. For example, as I've said, there's no `QHttpMultiPart` in PySide. You're just confusing everyone. Neither is the C++ tag helpful.

Comment: I said almost.anyway I edited my question and add PyQt4 to it.thanks for your help,if there is a solution on c++ so there is on PyQt4 too.

Comment: yes it's the same,but I'm sending just QNetworkRequest.ContentDispositionHeaderI didn't use QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader,plus,I didn't use setParent,instead I used deleteLater like this: self._multiPart.deleteLater() when finished signal emited,I also use self._file.close() to close file when finished signal is emited

Comment: I did test this code on local and got 70 Mb/s but in main program I just got 3 Mb/s almost all code was the same except I pass the file to Uploader with a loop,do you have any idea ?

Comment: Ok,I think I found that where is problem,I emit a signal from Uploader.uploadProgress() to Window.UploadProgress() to show progress to user,this is why speed is low,but still can't understand why

Comment: @Mohammadhzp. Glad to see you got your headers sorted out! As to your current question: are you saying that the actual upload speed is okay, but the _reported_ speed is wrong? If so, you will need to show how you are calcualting the speed, which will probably require a new question (with example code, of course).

Comment: Thanks,it turn out headers was fine,it was a bug on python3,I will update my question and write a more complete example to see what I do. I guess the problem is just when I emit uploadProgress in handleUploadProgress